# Image view to stretch fit table row width

Tags: android, android-layout

I have this layout XML that I want the ImageView in the second row to stretch to fit the row view if possible and the textview in the first row is stuck on the left of the screen and I would need it in the center. the ImageView is being filled with an image taken from the camera, any help is appreciated.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
>

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:stretchColumns="*" >

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow1" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Set Your Personal Information Here"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow2" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tableRow3" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <QuickContactBadge
                android:id="@+id/quickContactBadge1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Gender"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Credits"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: On the Linearlayout with the Imageview set the orientation to horizontal and remove the layout weight and on the Imageview add scaleType FIT_XY see if that does the trick.

Comment: `FIT_XY` is not a valid parameter though

Comment: Sorry its fitXY try that.

Comment: Yea, that did what I was looking for in this case

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As @Brosa said in comment, use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` attribute.

Althrough you have find your solution, I am writing this answer to write about a brief description about different option of `android:scaleType` for future help.

There are several options in this attreibute. They are

1. matrix
2. fitXY
3. fitStart
4. fitCenter
5. fitEnd
6. center
7. centerCrop
8. centerInside

Here is a small description for those from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html)

**1. matrix**
Scale using the image matrix when drawing.

**2. fitXY**
Scale the image in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This may change the aspect ratio of the src.

**3. fitStart**
Scale the image by computing a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. START aligns the result to the left and top edges of dst.

**4. fitCenter**
Scale the image by computing a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.

**5. fitEnd**
Scale the image by computing a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis (X or Y) will fit exactly. END aligns the result to the right and bottom edges of dst.

**6. center**
Center the image in the view, but perform no scaling.

**7. centerCrop**
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or larger than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

**8. centerInside**
Scale the image uniformly (maintain the image's aspect ratio) so that both dimensions (width and height) of the image will be equal to or less than the corresponding dimension of the view (minus padding).

Comment: Thanks for the break down, I was just looking for the other enum types as well